# Push a Javascript ID into a bootstrap modal (when existing feature in place...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I pass a value into a Bootstrap Modal? I have some basic HTML that looks like this:

```
<h2 class="name" itemprop="name">Name ABC</h2>
```

What I would like to see happen is for the 'NAME ABC' to be pushed or 'echoed' within a bootstrap modal..

I am assuming you use an 'id' but I' must not sure how to code that....

The HTML in the bootstrap would need

```
<input type="text" name=" ID " value=""/> * I think!! *
```

If anyone can jump in with the basic JavaScript to make this work I'd be very grateful! Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about this bootstrap modal?
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

Comment: That not really clear

Comment: just capture the text value using id and push it in to modal window element using id $('#modal_element_id').val($('#name').text());

Comment: When you want to populate the value to input

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){
  
  $("#modalInput").val($("#input").val());
  $("#modal_id").modal('show');
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Type a message : <input type="text" id="input">
<button id="submit">Send</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal_id">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        
        <h4 class="modal-title">Message!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Your Value : <input  type="text" id="modalInput" readonly/>
      </div>
             </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can instantiate a Bootstrap modal as normal, then simply add a click handler to the `h2` element which places its `text()` value within the target `input` in the modal. Try this:

```js
$('.name').click(function() {
  $('#foo').val($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="name" itemprop="name" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Name ABC</h2>

<h2 class="name" itemprop="name" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Name XYZ</h2>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="foo" name="ID" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try following

```
  $('input[name="ID"]').val($('h2.name').text());
```

```js
$('input[name="ID"]').val($('h2.name').text());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="name" itemprop="name">Name ABC</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" name="ID" value="" /> * I think!! *
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is getting value of text with class .name and setting it in as an id attribute, which is in modal box of bootstrap. If so following process will help.

html

```
<h2 class="name" itemprop="name">Name ABC</h2>

<a href="#" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">sdsdf</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="" class="myValue">One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
  var myTxt = $('.name').text();
  $('.myValue').attr('id', myTxt);
})
```

What I have done is taken text from div with class name "name" and but that in as a id attribute in modal div with class "myValue". Hope this helps